# Multiple light sources & implementation details around GLSL normal mapping shader

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl, lwjgl

The first issue, is how to get from a single light source, to using multiple light sources, without using more than one fragment shader.

My instinct is that each run through of the shader calculations needs light source coordinates, and maybe some color information, and we can just run through the calculations in a loop for n light sources.

How do I pass the multiple lights into the shader program? Do I use an array of uniforms? My guess would be do pass in an array of uniforms with the coordinates of each light source, and then specify how many light sources there are, and then set a maximum value.

Can I call getter or setter methods for a shader program? Instead of just manipulating the globals?

I'm using this tutorial and the libGDX implementation to learn how to do this:
https://gist.github.com/mattdesl/4653464

Comment: `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.shaders.DefaultShader` handles mutliple lights from the environment.  This package also contains a default vert/frag shader.  Might give you some inspirations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many methods to have multiple light sources. I'll point 3 most commonly used.

1) Specify each light source in array of uniform structures. Light calculations are made in shader loop over all active lights and accumulating result into single vertex-color or fragment-color depending if shading is done per vertex or per fragment. (this is how fixed-function OpenGL was calculating multiple lights)

2) Multipass rendering with single light source enabled per pass, in simplest form passes could be composited by additive blending (srcFactor=ONE dstFactor=ONE). Don't forget to change depth func after first pass from GL_LESS to GL_EQUAL or simply use GL_LEQUAL for all passes.

3) Many environment lighting algorithms mimic multiple light sources, assuming they are at infinte distance from your scene. Simplest renderer should store light intensities into environment texture (prefferably a cubemap), shader job then would be to sample this texture several times in direction around the surface normal with some random angular offsets.

Comment: I want to plus one this answer, but everything you just said is so far over my head that I don't really know where to start. I'm not a GL expert by any means. This is my first time working *directly* with OpenGL (as previously I've been letting libraries do the work).

Comment: What do you need? some glsl example? You may find [link] Nehe tutorials useful (http://nehe.gamedev.net/) it doesn't use libGDX but all fundeamental opengl and glsl concepts are explained and coded step by step.

Comment: I've actually gone with some lighting libraries that use raycasting to make directional lights. I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate normal-map lighting into that set of libraries. It's called Box2DLights. There are some videos where it's been done, but I'm at a loss as to how I could make it work.

Comment: Here is some code you may find useful. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79944/libgdx-box2dlights-shadow-offset-problem-on-bodies